# How to "permanently" turn off networking on an android device?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, mobile-network, data-connection, airplane-mode

I'm in the process of creating a "secure device" to store and process sensitive information. Using an Android device was the best course of action for me, since I can make a quick app, plus I can use the camera, finger print, and other goodies that comes with these. All development is going well, except that I want to have that device as isolated from any network activity as possible.

For now I'm just turning off WIFI, making sure Mobile Data is off, and setting airplane mode on. But, and where is my question: Is it possible to do it on a OS level? in such a way that there is no obvious way to turn it back on? I spend more than 2 hours searching around but most results are how-tos, or things unrelated to what I want to do.

Just to be clear, I do not want my app to do this, but instead, run a command or do something to the device that "physically" disables connectivity on the device.

I would love if this does not require a custom android build.

I would accept purchase recommendations for devices that comes without connectivity at all.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `ip` or `iptables` to block everything at kernel level. Both commands require root. Or go one step further ahead and rebuild your kernel with network stack entirely disabled.

Comment: Was already reading about rebuilding the kernel, but seems like a lot of work xD
iptables can be VERY interesting. Will check it out. Thanks @IrfanLatif

Comment: Wouldn't just removing the driver for networking prevent network connectivity as it simply wouldn't function

Comment: Would you mind pointing me towards making this happen @Archerbob? 
I'm no android dev. Would it need a rebuild? Can it be done simply as root?

Comment: I thought removing the driver would be easier but it seems not, it seems the way to go perhaps is to use IPTABLES with DROP/REJECT so packets cannot enter/leave the device. Have a read at https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/hidl/network-stack and the man page of iptables https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Comment: Don't forget to remove the radio layer. Most of the GSM functionality (e.g. SMS) does not make use of IP (only the recent standards like VoLTE). Or you simply use a Wifi only tablet - that would simplify the task.

Comment: Thanks @Archerbob reading your links.

Comment: @Robert great point. Would you guide me towards a starting point?

Comment: Radio layer is already the starting point. I only know RIL which is the Radio Layer Interface on the higher levels and on the lower layer there is the radio layer providing services on cellular networks.

Comment: Does GSM work without a SIM card?  I thought if there was no SIM in the device that GSM functionality didn't work